# MyClassBase or BaseMyClass?

Tags: naming-conventions, class-design, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Using “Base” in a Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510839/using-base-in-a-class-name)
>   [C# Class naming convention: Is it BaseClass or ClassBase or AbstractClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826821/c-class-naming-convention-is-it-baseclass-or-classbase-or-abstractclass)
>   [Naming Conventions for Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429470/naming-conventions-for-abstract-classes)

What is the better way to name base abstract classes? I still can't decide where to put 'Base' word. Should it be 'BaseMyClass' or 'MyClassBase'?

How do you name those and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429470/naming-conventions-for-abstract-classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510839/using-base-in-a-class-name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826821/c-class-naming-convention-is-it-baseclass-or-classbase-or-abstractclass

Comment: Unless there's a concrete reason to use the words 'base' or 'class' I would avoid using them anyway.

Comment: Wow! I have the answer now. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine if you have a chain of abstract classes, would you call it MyClassBaseBaseBase then?

Avoid the use of "Base" in your name if you can. You have an abstract base class because it's somehow more generic than your concrete implementation. Name it in a more generic way then, describing what common ground it supplies for deriving classes.

If the above cant be done for some reason, I agree with the previous poster; use MyClassBase.

Comment: Of course you would, BaseBaseBaseFactoryFactoryFactories are all the rage.

Answer (score 3):

Subjective... But ok. This is my perception of things: `BaseMyClass` sounds like an imperative: "Base my class! Now!" :) 
Whereas `MyClassBase` is clearer... a class that is a Base

Comment: [`AllYourBaseClassAreBelongToUs`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIQ53t0gv_4)?

Comment: LOL... and ´WouldYouBaseMyClassPlease´

Answer (score 1):

**MyClassBase** is the way to go.

This is subjective but calling it MyClassBase brings readabilty and symmetry in design.

Comment: How about just `My`? What does `Class` or `Base` tell about the objects being modeled?

Comment: I think he won't ever need a class named like this. Rather he wants to know how to name classes generally (at least I hope so :)

Comment: Just using 'My' would too short of a meaning for the class imho.

Comment: Actually... 'MyClass' is kind of 'Foobar' word here. :) I never name classes that way.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the words "Base", "My" or "Class" at all but chose a name for the interface that actually describes what it is.

Answer (score 0):

A choice between between `MyClassBase` and `BaseMyClass` is like asking whether I'd prefer a kick in the nuts or a punch in the face.

I don't wish to offend, but both those names are awful. Specifically, there is no reason to include `Class` in the class name (unless you're modelling an eduction system). If you really need to use the class name to indicate it can't be instantiated, I would prefer to use the term `Abstract`, rather than `Base`.

As a general rule, look at how the standard libraries are named and follow that convention. If your standard libraries have names like `MyClassBase` and `BaseMyClass`, then naming is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct but when I name my base class I want that just by looking at the class name one should understand that this is meant to be inherited. like I have two versions of webpart(GoogleSearch) one for mobile and other for normal brower then I would create an abstract base named GoogleSearchWebpartBase and name the webparts as MobileGoogleSearch and GoogleSearch.