# C# abstract class naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

In C#, the interface naming convention is `I<myInterfaceName>` (ex: `IList`).

Are there any naming conventions for abstract classes?

If there aren't, what are the main recommendations?

Comment: Just a generic name that describes what the class does, tbh.

Comment: No, afaik,  there is no convention or best practice tied to abstract classes.

Comment: @DonBoitnott close vote for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429470/naming-conventions-for-abstract-classes this one as by duDE

Answer (score 37):

Normally, there is **no suffix/prefix** used when naming abstract classes, unlike interfaces, which have the prefix "I". Just give your class a name that describes what it is for, in a short precise way.

Comment: I've always seen Interfaces with an "I" **prefix** such as `IEnumerable` or `ITaxable`.

Comment: @JYelton I think that's just a grammar mistake and he means 'there is no suffix for abstract classes, unlike interfaces which have an I-prefix convention'

Answer (score 19):

> Are there a naming convention for abstract class ?

No, there are no conventions here. There are some *common* ways of denoting an abstract base class. The most common I've seen is to use the suffix `Base`. Personally, I do not like this convention, and the [Framework guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/12/16/basesuffix.aspx) recommend against it.

> And if there aren't what is the mains recommandations ?

A good, general name that describes what the class is modeling, just like any other class name. So `Shape` and then `Polygon` and then `RegularPolygon` so on.

Comment: Where do the framework guidelines recommend against it? You linked to the blog of one of the framework architects, not to the framework guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx (which do not appear to state anything either way).

Comment: Downvoted because I agree with @Pharap.

Comment: Presumably he linked to the blog post because the recommendation in the Framework Design Guidelines is in the book, pg. 174, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/429494/.

Comment: That convention specifically states "Base" should not be used if it's a public API. So it is fine to name abstract classes using "Base", if its intended use is internal to the library itself.